# Abstract Class vs. Lambda parameters

Tags: oop, inheritance, lambda, abstract, kotlin

Since kotlin has such good support for lambdas, I started to use lambdas as constructor parameters for `abstract` classes instead of declaring `abstract val/fun`.

It's more concise in my opinion, especially because `val` type get's inferred.

What are the downsides to this?

```
abstract class AbstractListScreen<T> (
    val data: Set<T>,
    val filterators: (T) -> Set<String>
) {

    fun open() {
        /* ... */
    }
}

class OrderListScreen : AbstractListScreen<Data>(data = setOf(),
                                                 filterators = { setOf(it.toString()) }
) {

    fun someEvent() {
        /* ...*/
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. In your example, each instance of `OrderListScreen` will create its own `filterators` instance of function type `(T) -> Set<String>`. This has additional run-time overhead in both memory and performance when compared with abstract functions and their overrides which are stored in the type definition at compile-time.
2. The default filterators can be stored in a property to reduce this run-time overhead:

   ```
   class OrderListScreen : AbstractListScreen<Data>(data = setOf(),
                                                    filterators = defaultFilterators
   ) {
       companion object {
           val defaultFilterators: (Data) -> Set<String> = { setOf(it.toString()) }
       }

       fun someEvent() {
           /* ...*/
       }
   }
   ```

   However, each instance of `OrderListScreen` will still have its own reference to `defaultFilterators` which is still additional run-time overhead (although marginal unless you have many instances of these types).
3. [Function types](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#function-types) such as `(T) -> Set<String>` may have named parameters (e.g. `(element: T) -> Set<String>`) but currently IDEs such as IntelliJ IDEA do not use those named parameters in generated documentation or code stubs so such information is lost when subclassing, etc. IDEs do use named parameters in generated documentation and code stubs for abstract functions.
4. You cannot (currently) associate documentation directly with the function type parameter which you can do with abstract functions.

When attempting to account for the run-time overhead the code doesn't look much different when using abstract functions, the run-time overhead is eliminated, and current IDE support for generated code stubs, documentation, etc. is improved:

```
abstract class AbstractListScreen<T>(val data: Set<T>) {
    abstract fun filterators(element: T): Set<String>

    fun open() {
        /* ... */
    }
}

class OrderListScreen : AbstractListScreen<Data>(data = setOf()) {
    override fun filterators(element: Data): Set<String> = setOf(element.toString())

    fun someEvent() {
        /* ...*/
    }
}
```

Comment: in fact, the code looks much cleaner and less puzzling ;)

Comment: I'll accept this answer, but I hoped to get more information about OOP and refactorization instead of practical (documentation & performance) issues…